# Is it possible to generate a list of urls in a page?

Tags: url, download

I need something like firefox's downthemall but without downloading the files, just exporting a list of urls to a txt file.
Anybody knows of a browser plugin or a standalone app that does it?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the "lynx" command and then parse its result this way:

```
giuseppe@scarafaggio:~$ LC_ALL=C lynx -dump http://www.google.it |awk 'NR==1,/References/{next};{print $2}'

http://www.google.it/imghp?hl=it&tab=wi
http://video.google.it/?hl=it&tab=wv
http://maps.google.it/maps?hl=it&tab=wl
http://news.google.it/nwshp?hl=it&tab=wn
http://www.google.it/shopping?hl=it&tab=wf
https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm
http://www.google.it/intl/it/options/
http://www.google.it/url?sa=p&pref=ig&pval=3&q=http://www.google.it/ig%3Fhl%3Dit%26source%3Diglk&usg=AFQjCNGj0rOYdXuivAAnOmwpag3BjbWBFg
http://www.google.com/history/optout?hl=it
http://www.google.it/preferences?hl=it
https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=it&continue=http://www.google.it/
http://www.google.it/advanced_search?hl=it
http://www.google.it/language_tools?hl=it
https://www.google.com/intl/it/policies/#utm_source=googlehp&utm_medium=hpp&utm_campaign=it_all-hpp_pp
http://www.google.it/intl/it/ads/
http://www.google.it/services/
http://www.google.it/intl/it/about.html
http://www.google.com/ncr
http://www.google.it/intl/it/privacy.html
```

Comment: what is "lynx"? can you direct me to an explanation? cant find anything useful about it in google..

Comment: Lynx is a web browser for terminal emulator. You may find more information about it at http://lynx.isc.org/current/ .

Comment: @AAaa did you find useful this answer?

Comment: @AAaa If you are satisfied with the answer you could accept it be clicking the tick mark next to the question and/or you could up vote the answer if this has helped you in any way. Accepting answers will enhance your reputation in this forum.